# Optional redis session storage for Spring MVC Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

I want to use spring-session to store my users' session data in a central location like a Redis server for load balancing without needing sticky sessions.

Spring supports this with just a few lines:

**Config.java**

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession 
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
            return new JedisConnectionFactory(); 
    }

}
```

And **Initializer.java**

```
public class Initializer
                extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer { 
}
```

However, now I'm tightly coupled to Redis in all my development environments, and every single deployment I make. I might only want to use Redis in one high-traffic deployment of this software.

I tried using Spring Profiles (added `@Profile("redissessions")` to **Config.java**) however there's no way I can tell my servlet container to not pick up **Initializer.java** (which causes the application to fail to startup if **Config.java** is excluded through a `@Profile`).

The end result I want is as if I had put `@Profile("redissessions")` on the **Initializer.java** class (which I don't think is possible) **OR** is there something I can swap the JedisConnectionFactory out for, that will delegate to some sort of internal (or servlet container) mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

In the project i'm working on i had to do this to handle a switch between Redis and no-Redis.

this file only replaces the "Initializer.java" file that you have, the other one still the same but u have to add the @Profile("nameOfYourProfileForUseRedis").

```
@Configuration
public class AppInitializer extends 
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException 
{
    WebApplicationContext webAppContext = getContext();

// Inicializacion de Filtro para Redis
    if("redis".equalsIgnoreCase(props.getProperty("spring.profiles.active"){
        addSpringSessionRepositoryFilter(servletContext, webAppContext);
    }

public void addSpringSessionRepositoryFilter(ServletContext servletContext, 
WebApplicationContext webAppContext) {
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic springSessionFilter = 
servletContext.addFilter("springSessionRepositoryFilter",
            new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSessionRepositoryFilter", 
webAppContext));
    springSessionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    System.out.println("Inicializacion de Filtro para Redis");
}
```